# Java binary search of custom objects using String key

Tags: java, collections, binary-search

I have a class

```
class User{
   String territory;
   String company;
   String name;
}
```

I have an arraylist of 'User' . I would like to lookup a User object from the list using the String 'territory+company' . The lookup should be based on Binary search. How could i implement it?

The Collections.binarySearch() needs us to create a dummy User object. I dont want that.

Comment: show us what you have tried..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implement binary search in objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901944/implement-binary-search-in-objects)

Comment: @AnoopLL I have tried Collections.binarySearch. But that requires a dummy object creation. I dont want that.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to implement the [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface for your `User` class. Then you can use `Collections.binarySearch()` method (only if your list is sorted of course).

Something like that would work for you:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List <User> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new User("A1", "B1", "Name1"));
        list.add(new User("A2", "B2", "Name2"));
        list.add(new User("A3", "B3", "Name3"));
        list.add(new User("A4", "B4", "Name4"));
        list.add(new User("A5", "B5", "Name5"));

        System.out.println(list.get(Collections.binarySearch(list, new User("A4", "B4", "Name4"))));
    }


    static class User implements Comparable <User>{
        String territory;
        String company;
        String name;

        public User(String territory, String company, String name) {
            this.territory = territory;
            this.company = company;
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(User o) {
            return (territory+company).compareTo(o.territory+o.company);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString(){
            return territory + "," + company + "," + name;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The OP was made more complete: "The Collections.binarySearch() needs us to create a dummy User object. I dont want that.". So this one no longer answers the question.

Comment: Did you got the answer. I also need the same.

Comment: the question explicitly asks for not having to create a dummy User object
But your answer creates it, you are not really answer this case